# How to use PullRefreshIndicator only as indicator, disable pull action by a user?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In View Android system we could make `SwipeRefreshLayout`  disabled (`android:enabled=false`) but still use its refreshing property for indication.

Is it possible in Compose?

```
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
    refreshing = refreshing,
    onRefresh = {}
)

PullRefreshIndicator(
    refreshing,
    pullRefreshState,
    Modifier
        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution which is quite simple

Just don't add `.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)`, which is quite logical, this one is used for manual swipe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```kotlin
if (refreshing) {
    PullRefreshIndicator(
        true,
        pullRefreshState,
        Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
    )
}
```

This way, the PullRefreshIndicator will be removed from the composables tree unless a refresh occurs.

Maybe also move the state inside the if block, but every time the `refreshing` value changes to false, the state will be reset when it is true again. So, test both cases and see what works better.